# Placing SQL files on SAN

Tags: sql, sql-server, networking, system, san

Recently I had a discussion with our Network and System team about putting SQL files on different SAN LUNs. They believed that now a days because of SAN EMC Management process it is wasting the time and energy to put SQL files (Data/Log/Lob/Index/Backups especially TLogs) on separate drives with different spindles. So, could you help me by participating and stating your idea and vision about this discussion please.

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2008/08/sql-server-on-a-san-dedicated-or-shared-drives/

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to agree with your SAN administrators on this one.  Most SANs today are running RAID-10 or similar technologies, spanning many drives and handling very high IOPS.  Physically separating spindles for SQL Server data and logs goes back to the days of local storage with low numbers of drives and low IOPS capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

so - its definitely worth placing your SQL data on separate LUNs, if only for scaling purposes. Definitely don't partition a LUN into multiple filesystems, I have seen that - its a road to destruction.

Putting different volumes on different physical spindles - this depends on a lot of factors.

Whats the workload, OLTP or OLAP (transactional or analytics)?
Whats the storage array? Is it traditional RAID (LUNs are on raidgroups) or is it virtualized provisioning (LUNs on "extents" Pools, extents on raidgroups (example VNX, VMAX, Unity))?
Are you using thin provisioning?
How are you going to scale?

Measure what workload are you dishing out to your current storage devices. Main thing, measure IOPS but also IO block size. IOPS alone is a meaningless number, you want to know the size of IO operations to determine volume placement. Determine what technology are you using, traditional or virtualized. Use latency as the ultimate performance measure.

This should get the conversation with your storage guys started.